# Calculate difference from earlier amount

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I calculate the difference if there is an earlier amount for the corresponding type?

```
| Type | Date    | Amt | Diff   |
|------|---------|-----|--------|
| A    | 1/07/18 | 10  |        |
| B    | 1/07/18 | 10  |        |
| A    | 1/07/19 | 15  | 50%    |
| A    | 1/07/20 | 12  | -20%   |
| B    | 1/07/20 | 15  | 50%    |
```

Comment: This seem structured data, so in `D2` use `=IF(A2=A1,(C2-C1)/C1,"")` and drag down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed the question from a structured dataset to a somewhat unstructured dataset. Dates still seem structured, yet 'Type' is ***not*** filtered. Therefor you could use the following in `D2`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)>1,(C2-LOOKUP(2,1/(A$1:A1=A2),C$1:C1))/LOOKUP(2,1/(A$1:A1=A2),C$1:C1),"")
```

Drag down.

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question?!

> `D1` =IF(ROW()=MATCH(A2,A:A,0),"",((C2-INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A2,A:A,0),1))*100/INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A2,A:A,0),1)) & "%")

Output

```
A   7/21/2020   10  
B   7/22/2020   10  
A   7/23/2020   15  50%
A   7/24/2020   12  20%
B   7/25/2020   15  50%
C   7/26/2020   13  
A   7/27/2020   15  50%
A   7/28/2020   12  20%
B   7/29/2020   15  50%
C   7/30/2020   26  100%
A   7/31/2020   13  30%
```

Comment: You are checking against the *first* match each time yielding the wrong results.